# Resolving Implementation at Runtime

Tags: java

```java
// interface defined in Coffee.jar.
interface Coffee {
  void brew();

  void discard();
}


// implementation defined in BlackCoffee.jar
class BlackCoffee implements Coffee {
  @Override
  public void brew() {
    System.out.println("Brew BalckCoffee");
  }

  @Override
  public void discard() {
    System.out.println("Discard BlackCoffee");

  }
}


// implementation defined in FilterCoffee.jar
class FilterCoffee implements Coffee {

  @Override
  public void brew() {
    System.out.println("Brew FilterCoffee");

  }

  @Override
  public void discard() {
    System.out.println("Discard FilterCoffee");

  }
}

// Runtime class in Coffee.jar
class BrewCoffee {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Coffee coffee = //something here;
    coffee.brew();
    coffee.discard();
  }
}
```

Then idea is to resolving the implementation at runtime without knowing the implementation.
The app would have the dependency of Coffee.jar and one from either BlackCoffee.jar or FilterCoffee.jar .

Comment: could you go into a little more detail about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the advantages of a dependency injection framework (like Spring).

You code to interfaces and your client classes don't know which implementation is instantiated at runtime.

You could pick which based on conditions 
e.g. in Spring you can use @Conditional property

```
@ConditionalOnProperty("coffee.black")
class BlackCoffee implements Coffee 

@ConditionalOnProperty("coffee.filter")
class BlackCoffee implements Coffee
```

and then have

```
@Component
class ClassUsingCoffee {
    private Coffee coffee;

    @Inject
    public ClassUsingCoffee(Coffee coffee) {
        this.coffee = coffee;
    }

    //use coffee as normal
}
```

then in your Spring's properties you can define property "black" or "filter" to activate one of the two concrete class implementations. If you defined both of the properties you'd get an exception saying that 2 instances of Coffee exist and it doesn't know which to inject (dependency inject) into your `ClassUsingCoffee` class

It's hard to explain without going into the detail of Spring too much. But you could also use the `ApplicationContext` (think of it as a "thing" that holds all the classes Spring knows about)

```
class BrewCoffee {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = //omitted for brevity
        Coffee coffee = ctx.getBean(Coffee.class);
        coffee.brew();
        coffee.discard();
  }
```

In both examples you have coupled the classes to the `Coffee` interface rather a specific implementation. e.g. if you did `Coffee coffee = new BlackCoffee()` then your code is coupled to a specific implementation of Coffee (in this case `BlackCoffee`) and any changes required would require code changes (as opposed to config/property changes)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the implementation of an interface to be chosen because of the existence of the jar file with the implementation on the classpath, then you should use the Service Loader framework.

See [The Java™ Tutorials - Creating Extensible Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) for more information.

In your case, start by organizing your code, i.e. put the classes in packages:

```
package com.example.api;

public interface Coffee {
    ...
}
```

```
package com.example.black;

import com.example.api.Coffee;

public class BlackCoffee implements Coffee {
    ...
}
```

```
package com.example.filter;

import com.example.api.Coffee;

public class FilterCoffee implements Coffee {
    ...
}
```

```
package com.example;

import com.example.api.Coffee;

public class BrewCoffee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Coffee coffee : ServiceLoader.load(Coffee.class)) {
            coffee.brew();
            coffee.discard();
        }
    }
}
```

Then package it like this:

- Put `com/example/api/Coffee.class` in file `coffee.jar`
- Put `com/example/black/BlackCoffee.class` in file `black.jar` together with file `META-INF/services/com.example.api.Coffee` with content `com.example.black.BlackCoffee`
- Put `com/example/filter/FilterCoffee.class` in file `filter.jar` together with file `META-INF/services/com.example.api.Coffee` with content `com.example.filter.FilterCoffee`
- Put `com/example/BrewCoffee.class` in file `brew.jar`

You can now run the program using one of the following commands:

```
java -cp brew.jar;coffee.jar;black.jar com.example.BrewCoffee
```

```
java -cp brew.jar;coffee.jar;filter.jar com.example.BrewCoffee
```

```
java -cp brew.jar;coffee.jar;black.jar;filter.jar com.example.BrewCoffee
```

<sup>*Note:* On Linux, replace `;` with `:`</sup>

Since the `main` method is looping through all implementations, the third command will run with both `BlackCoffee` and `FilterCoffee`.